# android php post issue

Tags: php, android

I'm currently working on an android app which retrieves mysql data via a php script which I'm running locally, but I keep getting a httpconnection error which states that it cannot connect to the script (http://127.0.0.1/regions.php) I'm running on my local server.  The code is as follows:

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.apache.*;
import org.apache.http.*;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.*;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.paypal.android.MEP.*;

public class ShoppingCartActivity extends Activity {

    JSONArray jArray;
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);      
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        InputStream is = null;
        StringBuilder sb = null;
        String result = null;

        //http post
        try{
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://127.0.0.1/regions.php");
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();//this holds returned content
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection"+e.toString());
        }

        //convert response to string
        try{
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
            sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append(reader.readLine() + "\n");
            String line="0";

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }

            is.close();
            result=sb.toString();

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
        }

        //parsing data
        int reg_id;
        String reg_name;
        try{
        jArray = new JSONArray(result);
        JSONObject json_data=null;

        for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
               reg_id=json_data.getInt("RegionID");
               reg_name=json_data.getString("RegionName");
        }

        }catch(JSONException e1){
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No Regions Found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }catch (ParseException e1){
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

---

Here is the php script that I'm posting to:

```
<?php
$conn = mysql_connect("127.0.0.1","",""); 
mysql_select_db("thebigchoice") or die(mysql_error()); 

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM REGIONS WHERE RegionName LIKE 's%'", $conn) or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {

 $data[] = $row;

   } 

print json_encode($data); 

mysql_close($conn); 

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `10.0.2.2` instead of `127.0.0.1` (in android code)
Explication here: [Network addresses](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/emulator.html#networkaddresses)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access local host, however this is the localhost for the computer, not the Android device. If you are running your code on a real device, the device needs to be in the same network as the computer and you should change the host to the network ip of your machine, rather than the ip for localhost (`127.0.0.1`).

If you are running on emulator, then as @enrmarc wrote you cna try using this special IP to access the localhost of the desktop.

`127.0.0.1` -> `10.0.2.2`

Answer (score 0):

In android code, the `HttpPost("http://127.0.0.1/regions.php");` may be invaild

Because the localhost of developing machine and testing device are difference.

You can connect developing machine and testing device to a network and get the network address of developing machine to test

Or upload php scirpt to a free host to test

Happy coding :D